Unable to download any plugins in Jenkins
Problem: I m getting an error when I navigate to manage plugin

There were errors checking the update sites: FileNotFoundException: http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?id=default&version=2.319.3

Available Plugins are showing as empty
HTTP Proxy Configuration
Update Site
I tried to search some plugin as "Maven, git", But I can't find any.
Expected Result: I want to see the list of plugins when I search.

Is the proxy details correct?. it looks like jenkins is not able to talk to internet.

I'm new to Jenkins. I don't know what is the issue and how to resolve this issue.
As I given Server ip address is my local ip address

you don't need to give proxy details. try removing them and check again.
